# Joomla Lof ArticleSlideShow Configuring Articles

Tags: joomla, module, slideshow, configure

I can't get how to use this module (Lof Article Slide Show), it says you have either to use the categories (ok, i got that) or the article id's.

However, articles don't have any space in options that you can assign a class, an id's or anything similiar to Menus (where classes can be applied) or even better like modules (where also id's can be applied).

Comment: have you tried contacting the developers of the module?

Comment: Of course, they are inaccessble and I am not the only one who has these problems, others complain for the lack of support or documentation.
  
 


Thanks for the reply, however, I figured out what Articile ID refers to just a few minuntes ago. It refers to each article's ID which is given from the core Joomla that you can see on the far right in Article Manager.

This discussion is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what Articile ID refers to. It refers to each article's ID which is given from the core Joomla that you can see on the far right in Article Manager.